# Undefined offset 0 in ActiveRecord/lib/Model.php on line 573

Tags: primary-key, phpactiverecord

I am using `phpactiverecord`. We have a table without a primary key and method `save()` generated this error:

`Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/vasiliy/sites/api/lib/ActiveRecord/lib/Model.php on line 573`

In `line 573` `phpactiverecord`, it tries to use the primary key value, but it is not set because the table does not have a `primary key`.

What can I do if my table has no `primary key`?

Answer (score 3):

php-activerecord requires primary keys, there's nothing you can do about it.
So, either add the primary key to the table (which is probably a very good idea), or don't use activerecord for the job.

Comment: Adding a primary key can be a simple extra column, auto-increment, doens't need any of your code to change really

Comment: if you using *InnoDB*, this one like to have a primary key so it knows where to put the stuff on the disk, you'll get a better clustered data (on this id) instead of more random one. ref: http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql